# Android StringRequest Volley not send post value

Tags: android, post, android-volley

i'm using android volley , and i want to send post data with stringRequest . 
but the param doesnt send to server . here is my code :

```
        StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,  new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                Log.d(TAG,  response);


    }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Volley Error: " + error.getMessage());


            }

        })
    {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "openApp");
                Log.d("Params", params + "");

                return params;
            }
        };

    jsonObjReq.setShouldCache(false);


        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

i dont know what is the wrong ?

Comment: are you adding the volley request in the RequestQueue ?

Comment: yes i added and i  update the code ,

Comment: First try to  check whether post request is getting send through other browser based addons like rest easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes the error is about server and my code is correct .

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `getParams`, you should use `getBody` for your POST request.

You can refer to my following working sample code (replace my `JSONObject` and Url by yours). Hope this helps!

```
        ...   
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("Title", "Android Volley POST DATA Demo");
            jsonBody.put("Author", "BNK");
            jsonBody.put("Date", "2015/11/01");
            requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // do something...
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // do something...
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    try {
                        return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            };
            queue.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ...
```

Comment: not worked . i used getParams() last week and work correctly but suddenly its crashed .

Comment: Suddendly crashed? Any logcat available?

Comment: this code not working , getParams work last week but now not working .and no params send to server . D/Response﹕ {"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameter 'tag' is missing!"}

Comment: Check your server app to see if it has had any changes or not. Looks like you don't send the "tag" parameter as server requirement?